# Google Nest Hub can't play HLS,But the HLS URL does work in HTML

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

1.We are debugging our smart home camera stream using Google Nest Hub.

2.We have access to device sync and passed the validator.This is our Device Sync response:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "b4ad4e18-ab90-4b0e-bc02-264da5bb6469",
        "devices": [{
            "traits": ["action.devices.traits.CameraStream"],
            "name": {
                "defaultNames": ["Imilab"],
                "name": "camera1",
                "nicknames": ["camera1"]
            },
            "attributes": {
                "cameraStreamNeedAuthToken": false,
                "cameraStreamSupportedProtocols": ["hls"],
                "cameraStreamNeedDrmEncryption": false
            },
            "id": "gejiayu2",
            "type": "action.devices.types.CAMERA",
            "deviceInfo": {
                "model": "a1znn6t1et8",
                "manufacturer": "Imilab"
            }
        }]
    },
    "requestId": "8664974301718985362"
}
```

3.We provide the HLS address, which can be played normally using ffplay [ffplay info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgjj4.jpg) or HTML, This is our demo HLS URL: https://cdn.cnbj2.fds.api.mi-img.com/cloud-storage-test/test1.m3u8.

4.But we can't use Google Nest Hub to play it. I recorded the debug video in the attachment. This is our camera stream response:

```
    {
    "payload": {
        "commands": [{
            "ids": ["gejiayu2"],
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "states": {
                "cameraStreamReceiverAppId": "",
                "cameraStreamAuthToken": "",
                "cameraStreamAccessUrl": "https://cdn.cnbj2.fds.api.mi-img.com/cloud-storage-test/test1.m3u8"
            }
        }]
    },
    "requestId": "1625829984244045201"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested Google Home and Google Home Mini and neither is capable of playing HLS streams. Our radio station is in the TuneIn database which supplies Google devices with radio streams. Our Icecast streams work but not HLS streams. So I'm sure that your Google Nest Hub has the same lack of ability to play HLS.